# ubuntu 16.04 : getting signature by key uses weak digest algorithm (sha1)

Tags: apt, 16.04, apache2, php, phpmyadmin

New on Ubuntu ..
I'm getting these warning after

```
$ sude apt-get update
```

---

```
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

W: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key C47415DFF48C09645B78609416126D3A3E5C1192 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)

W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Actually I tried to install PHP, Apache, MYSql, phpMyadmin

First I installed PHP, then Apache and Then Mysql server and then I tried to Install phpMyadmin then it gives me some missing error on PhpMyadmin
Error was kind of : mbstring missing

so i search for issue and ran some command on terminal after that i find out i need to install PPA repository then i installed it and then i retried to install phpMyadmin and now this is what happening..

Getting Warning Messages.

Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: @karel - NO Its not dupplicate, that question is related to Google repository. I dont know mine is related to same or not but i never installed Chrome in my system.

Comment: *Debian and Ubuntu enforce SHA256 or higher entries in the Release and/or Packages files since [March‌](https://juliank.wordpress.com/2016/03/14/dropping-sha-1-support-in-apt/)​. Repositories missing these need to be fixed by their owners.* This quote was taken from one of the answers to the linked question that you didn't read.

Comment: ok.. Then what is the solution?  How can i remove these broken packages?

Comment: Nothing is broken. It is just a warning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have the answer for my own question, may be that is a bad idea but now i'm able to do everything without any warning messages.

I have reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 and then installed PHP, Apache, and phpMyadmin without any problem. Seems like i had messed up with unity systems by running some random command.

Comment: I'm replying to your comment here because it makes more sense to reply to it here. The terminal keeps a history of the last 2000 commands which can be shown using the `history` command. If there was some random command that messed up your system you would have been able to find it that way. And PPAs can mess your system up.

Comment: @karel - Thanks for your comment , I appreciate for your information as i said i have less experience in Ubuntu and i tried to undo things but it didn't happens Thats why i had to do this to my save time. but for next time i will take care of every command before executing them.